# How to configure multi modules gradle build such that a module is built last

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, multi-module

I have a multi modules gradle build as follow

```
root \
    moduleA \
    moduleB \
    moduleC \
```

where `moduleB` depends on `moduleA`.

I want `moduleB` to be built last regardless whether `moduleB` depends on `moduleC`or not. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [evaluationDependsOn](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sub:configuration_time_dependencies)

```
project(':moduleB') {
    evaluationDependsOn(':moduleC')
}
```